# Graduation letter vs certificate

Tags: graduation, certification, validation

Someone graduated from a university few months ago. She asked for certificate but university staff informed that it will take around 9 months to be ready and stamped from authorities. They offered to give Graduation Letter signed from university only and transcript.

The degree is in Arabic Literature.
Can she use this letter for registration in another university for post-graduate studies or finding jobs as a teacher. she is looking to study/work in another country.

Thanks

Comment: Apply and find out. Check with the relevant Admissions department.

Comment: What @SolarMike says is correct. However, I think that most places will accept it since it is something that can be verified with the university if required.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on a lot of things? Including localisation, especially since at least 2 countries are involved.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened because the answer is "Yes," which does not depend on "a given institution’s regulations."  Feel free to prove me wrong by identifying an institution where the answer is "No."

Answer (score 2):

> Can she use this letter for registration in another university for post-graduate studies or finding jobs as a teacher?

**Yes**, but, whether it will be accepted depends on the recipient. You could check with the recipient to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is quite common - for instance, in Spain, higher degree certificates are signed by the king. And that takes a while. So these letters of degree completion issued by the university on behalf of the king are quite accepted, at least on the European level (see. e.g., [here](https://www.universityadmissions.se/en/All-you-need-to-know1/Applying-for-studies/Documenting-your-eligibility-for-studies/Instructions-for-Masters-applicants/Specific-requirements-for-my-country1/spain/)).

Whether the person in question will be able to use the letter depends a bit on where she applies. As one example, German universities will use an official database to check whether the degree credentials are sufficient or not. For the case of Spain, the database will list such letters as officially recognized, and hence they are sufficient.